# Set focus on validation summary after errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I've got 3 validation summary's in 3 seperate panels. Inside are some GridViews/DetailViews that on clicking update/submit refreshes to set focus on the top of the page. How do I set focus on the validation summary for each panel?

Comment: I don't know if you can really set the focus on a validation summary. Focus can be given to input controls but validation summaries are usually just lists of text items. That being said, you can try calling `ValidationSummary1.Focus()` in code-behind and see if it scrolls the content into view.

Comment: One more thing: in order to bring the panel itself into view, you may need to call the `Focus` method of the panel.